# Script on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a script on button click .. Here function `summarydata`  does not call.

Also when I check console there is not a single error. Where is the problem? any solution please?

```
    <button id="chartid" type="button" runat ="server">Show</button>
```

CODE

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string summarydata()
        {

            try
            {
                T1 sd = new T1();
                var data = new TrackDataEntities1().spsumdata().Select(s => new { name = s.Month, data = new int[] { s.data.Value } }).ToArray();
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

        }
```

**UPDATED**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          alert("iooooooooooooo");
           $(function () {
              $('[ID*=chartid]').on('click', function () {
                  alert("i");
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "WebForm1.aspx/summarydata",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      async: true,
                      cache: false,
                      success: function (result) {
                          alert(result.d);
                          alert("i");
                      },

                      error: function (error) {

                          alert(error);
                      }

                  });
              });

 </script>
```

When i set breakpoint on web method and click on button then breakpoint does not call

Comment: Place the `click` event inside `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 2):

your js code should be in `$(document).ready()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          alert("iooooooooooooo");
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#chartid").click(function() {
                  alert("i");
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "WebForm1.aspx/summarydata",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      async: true,
                      cache: false,
                      success: function (result) {
                          alert(result.d);
                          alert("i");
                      },

                      error: function (error) {

                          alert(error);
                      }

                  });
              });
});

 </script>
```

Comment: i also try this but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other option like using .on() like this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("iooooooooooooo");
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#chartid").on( "click",function() {
              alert("i");
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "WebForm1.aspx/summarydata",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: true,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function (result) {
                      alert(result.d);
                      alert("i");
                  },

                  error: function (error) {

                      alert(error);
                  }

              });
          });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place inside document ready / include script before end of body tag / use $(document).on("click","#chartid",function(){} ) instead .click . Because it will search for element with ID as chartid from root document object.